# Javascript LZ String compression check if string is already compressed

Tags: javascript, string, compression, lzw

I am using the LZ String library https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string/ to compress/decompress strings and save them in localStorage.

Since the compression is going to be applied on an existing project having customers with uncompressed strings already saved on localStorage. Is there a way to know if saved string is already compressed?

Sometimes when you try to decompress an uncompressed string you get `Null` or an empty string but some characters still are "wrongly" decompressed. For example:

```
LZString.decompressFromUTF16("O"); //returns null
LZString.decompressFromUTF16("J"); //returns string 0x80
```

Also if I try to decompress the word `Jam` I don't get a Null or empty result just a string;

```
LZString.decompressFromUTF16("Jam"); //returns string 0x80
```

Here is a JsFiddle with an example https://jsfiddle.net/imurphy/8c94mhxw/

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think a better structured alternative would be to save the compressed strings in such a format that you can easily detect whether it's compressed or not. For example, rather than doing:

```
localStorage.property = someCompressedString;
```

do something like

```
localStorage.property = JSON.stringify({ compressed: true, payload: someCompressedString });
// or, if there isn't a chance of collisions with the following approach:
localStorage.property = 'compressed-true---' + someCompressedString;
```

and then check if the value is JSON-parseable or starts with `compressed-true---`, and extract the compressed string part as needed.

Comment: That's great!, but I was wondering if there was some sort of a built in alternative, something like `LZString.isCompressed(string)`  or some other way to create a function to detect compressed strings.